# Javascript Async Function - .map - order of operation

Tags: javascript, async-await

Struggling to setup this function using async and await.

I have a function which maps over an object array. For each object, we make some external axios requests, receive a response before outputting an update object. I need to map over each object, update and return an array of updated objects.

Problem I am having, is that the output is not waiting for the resolved promise, resulting in undefined values being pushed to my array.

I note the array is also being logged before we handle each of the objects.

The following two functions are in question:

To build the object:

```js
const createHRObj = async function (workflow) {
    if (workflow.type_of_leave === "Personal") {
      getAbsenceDetail(
        `${workflow.employeeID}`,
        `${workflow.startDate}`,
        `${workflow.endDate}`
      ).then((res) => {
        try {
          console.log(`------- Handling Personal Leave! ----------`);
          console.log(workflow);

          if (res.Status != 0)
            throw new Error(`PeopleHR absence status code: ${res.Status}`);

          let absences = res.Result;

          if (absences.length === 0) workflow.on_PeopleHR = false;

          if (absences.length > 0) {
            let count = 0;
            absences.forEach((absence) => {
              if (
                Date.parse(absence.StartDate) <=
                  Date.parse(workflow.startDate) &&
                Date.parse(absence.EndDate) >= Date.parse(workflow.endDate)
              )
                count++;
            });

            count > 0
              ? (workflow.on_PeopleHR = true)
              : (workflow.on_PeopleHR = false);
          }

          console.log(`------- Absence Workflow Output! ----------`);
          console.log(workflow);
          console.log(
            `------- Updating and returning workflow! ----------`
          );
          return workflow;
          // console.log(`------- output from checkedarray ----------`);
          // console.log(checkedArray)
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      });

      // Else, check for holiday
    } else {
      getHolidayDetail(
        `${workflow.employeeID}`,
        `${workflow.startDate}`,
        `${workflow.endDate}`
      ).then((res) => {
        try {
          console.log(`------- Handling Business Leave! ----------`);
          console.log(workflow);

          if (res.data.Status != 10)
            throw new Error(
              `PeopleHR holiday status code: ${res.data.Status}`
            );

          let holidays = res.data.Result;

          if (holidays.length === 0) workflow.on_PeopleHR = false;

          if (holidays.length > 0) {
            let count = 0;
            holidays.forEach((holiday) => {
              if (
                Date.parse(holiday.StartDate) <=
                  Date.parse(workflow.startDate) &&
                Date.parse(holiday.EndDate) >= Date.parse(workflow.endDate)
              )
                count++;
            });

            count > 0
              ? (workflow.on_PeopleHR = true)
              : (workflow.on_PeopleHR = false);
          }

          console.log(`------- Absence Workflow Output! ----------`);
          console.log(workflow);
          console.log(
            `------- Updating and returning workflow! ----------`
          );
          return workflow;
          // console.log(`------- output from checkedarray ----------`);
          // console.log(checkedArray)
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

The second function, which calls the above function to handle the object creation is as follows:

```js
const peopleHR_Check = async function (workflows) {
  console.log(`----- We're now inside the PeopleHR Checker -------`);

  Promise.all(
    workflows.map(async (workflow) => {
      let outputObj = await createHRObj(workflow)
      return outputObj
    })
  )

  .then(res => console.log(res))
};
```

Comment: is either of the `console.log(err)` inside `createHRObj` logging anything? You're not giving much detail on what is output at your many `console.log` points, but if `undefined` is coming up here the most likely explanation is if either of those `catch` blocks is reached, because in those cases the promise returned by `createHRObj` will resolve to `undefined`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return the Promise from the `async` function `createHRObj`:

```js
return getAbsenceDetail(...).then(...)
```

However, it is simpler to use `await` since it is an `async` function for more linear flow.

```js
const res = await getAbsenceDetail(...);
// use res (move the code in .then() here)
// return the final output at the end
```